# Inherit pug file from a NPM package

Tags: pug

I'm importing a pug file using this syntax:

```
extends ../../../../shared/src/views/layouts/default.pug
```

For reuse propose, exists a way to import it from a NPM package like:

```
extends @matchlayer/shared/src/views/layouts/default.pug
```

Comment: Not natively within Pug, but you could write a node process that replaces that package path shorthand with the real path before Pug compiles.

Comment: I understand what you say and I saw implementations of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No. Pug has no concept of NPM or any other package manager. Only file path.

https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html